# How to have different drag behaviour in d3

Tags: d3.js

I want the elements inside the group to draggable and when I drag the parent group(g element), the elements inside group should also be dragged along with parent

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/2m006s9n/

Here's what I have tried:

```
            function moveCircle() {
                d3.select(this)
                        .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                        .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
            }

 //Append target circle to g element
    targetG.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 25)  //get radius from targetCircle and also styles?
            .attr("id", "circleAddedId")
            .classed("circleAddedClass", true)
            .attr("cx", d3.mouse(this)[0])
            .attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1])
            .style("fill", "white")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .call(
                    d3.behavior.drag()
                    .on('drag', moveCircle).origin(function () {
                var t = d3.select(this);
                return {x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy")};
            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the drag event from propagating to the container when you are dragging the circle

```
.on("dragstart", function () {
   d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
})
```

---

Note - the original code will work in Chrome, but not in IE. The translate function attributes can be separated by , (as in Chrome) or by space (as in IE).

To make it work in both you need to change the code that parses out your translate coordinates to try a split with space if the split with , returns only 1 element.

Just add this after your current split

```
if (translate.length === 1)
    translate = translate[0].split(' ');
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/x1jr1bfp/

Comment: Tried it but element inside the group is not draggable. I am able to drag only group but not circle inside it. I am using chrome latest

Comment: Oops, my bad! I missed the part about the elements within the group being draggable. Will update answer in a while.

Comment: Thanks potatopeelings. I had an idea about `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();` but didn't knew it should go in to 'dragstart'. i was actually trying it in `drag`. Anyway the basic idea is to add/remove elements in and out of group on dragging. Any hints on how to go about it?

Comment: Just do the bounds checking again when you drag out and append it back to svg.